# .length stops working after first pass using .blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

length to validate a user input field . it works fine on the first attempt but if i go back and change the field it doesn't update .

```
$("#user").blur(function () {
if ($("#user").val().length < 3) {
    $("#userval").addClass("valincorrect").html($("#user").val().length);

} else {
    $("#userval").addClass("valcorrect");
};
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

forgot to remove the old class

```
$("#user").blur(function () {
    if ($("#user").val().length < 3) {
        $("#userval").removeClass("valcorrect").addClass("valincorrect").html($("#user").val().length);
    }
    else {
        $("#userval").removeClass("valincorrect").addClass("valcorrect");
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it works, you just need to remove the 'valincorrect' class if the value is then marked as correct. Likewise for 'valcorrect'. Try just using 1 class, and using [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with comparing length using dom.

Try this
http://jsfiddle.net/FccPH/1/

Also better to save the chars if ur gonna reuse them